# Where is my location toolchain?

Tags: build, makefile, kernel-module, toolchain

I recently installed a toochain on BeagleBoard-xM, that targets to ARM architecture:
`opkg install task-native-sdk`.

Now, I want to run `make`, in order to build a module. For this reason, I must edit Makefile. Makefile instructions refer:

1. *Ensure that the $PATH variable includes the location of the toolchain that you will be using to cross-compile the module.*

I can see that there is an `arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi` folder under `usr`. Is that what I 'm looking for? In that case I should edit: `CROSS_COMPILE := /usr/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi`

1. *Set the KSRC environment variable is set to the location of your Beagleboard's kernel source.*

If I am correct, kernel sources are under: `usr/src/linux-2.6.32.61`. Is that what I should edit?

Comment: `I recently installed a toochain on BeagleBoard-xM` Is your toolchain is cross-compiler toolchain or Native ARM toolchain?

Comment: Is a native ARM toolchain. In this case, what should I edit on field "CROSS_COMPILE:"? I think it is better to build module on a Linux host machine with a cross-compiler toolchain and then copy the compiled module `.ko` to the target machine.

Comment: IF its native arm tool chain why you are cross-compiling it just run make in driver folder. If its cross-compiler then pls cross-compile it on x86 then copy .ko

Comment: Thank's for the replies. One thing I can't figure out: I 'll cross-compile on a x86 machine. On KVER I 'll edit the BB-xM's kernel version (2.6.32), but what I must edit on KSRC? Do I have to copy the BB kernel sources to x86 machine and edit the path of BB sources?

Comment: is that kernel source-code compiled one ?

Comment: Yes, by running `make` for building kernel and `make install` for installing it (both commands on BB).

Comment: KSRC=<path to compiled source-code>

Comment: I would be appreciated, if you had a look on a new query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598853/cross-compiling-kernel-module-for-arm/22600239?noredirect=1#22600239. Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$~ which arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
```

to check the location of your tool chain. Since you do `opkg install` it will be usually installed in usr/bin.

If you can do  `which arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi` and it shows the location of the tool chain that means its already there in your `PATH` variable, you don't  have to again set in the Makefile. The `CROSS_COMPILE` variable must be `CROSS_COMPILE := arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-`

`KSRC` must be source path of beagleboard's kernel source not your x86 pc's kernel source. You might build kernel for beagleboard on your pc and flash that kernel on the board. Then the KSRC may be location of the kernel where you built it.

Comment: I had downloaded kernel sources from kernel.org and after putting them under `usr/src` on BeagleBoard-xM, I build kernel. Isn't that my BB-xM's source path?

Comment: I have a query. Where are you doing this `Now, I want to run make in my home directory, in order to build a module.` board/x86?

Comment: I run make, in order to build it, in BB-xM. Sorry for not making it clear.

Comment: Sorry I am not that sure about BB-xM but usually the rule is while building module, KSRC should be path containing kernel source code (running same kernel , this is needed because of configuration).
if you have build kernel, flashed it on the board, and putting the source code to usr/src then your KSRC can be usr/src