# Cross-compiling kernel module for ARM

Tags: build, linux-kernel, kernel, arm, cross-compiling

I want to cross-compile *rtl8192cu driver* targeting ARM Angstrom *(BeagleBoard)*, on x86 Ubuntu 13.04.

Cross-compile prerequisites:

1. rtl8192cu driver
2. Cross-toolchain *(CodeSourcery / arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi)*
3. kernel sources

For this reason, I copied kernel sources *usr/src* directory of BeagleBoard, on Ubuntu machine *(they heve been compiled on BeagleBoard, as I needed to rebuild the kernel)*.

Running `make` for cross-compile, I get this error:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/demetres/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi- -C /home/demetres/Desktop/ks1 M=/home/demetres/Desktop/rtl3  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/demetres/Desktop/ks1'
  CC [M]  /home/demetres/Desktop/rtl3/core/rtw_cmd.o
/bin/sh: scripts/basic/fixdep: cannot execute binary file
make[2]: *** [/home/demetres/Desktop/rtl3/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 126
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/demetres/Desktop/rtl3] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/demetres/Desktop/ks1'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

If I run `file fixdep` I get:

```
fixdep: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, not stripped
```

This makes sense, as fixdep, is part of kernel sources *(compiled on ARM platform)*.

***My query is:*** Is that procedure correct and how can I fix this error?

***EDIT:***

Running `make V=1`:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/demetres/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi- -C /home/demetres/Desktop/ks M=/home/demetres/Desktop/rtl  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/demetres/Desktop/ks'
test -e include/linux/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
    echo;                               \
    echo "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
    echo "         include/linux/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";  \
    echo "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
    echo;                               \
    /bin/false)
mkdir -p /home/demetres/Desktop/rtl/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /home/demetres/Desktop/rtl/.tmp_versions/*
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=/home/demetres/Desktop/rtl
  /home/demetres/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wp,-MD,/home/demetres/Desktop/rtl/core/.rtw_cmd.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /home/demetres/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3/include -Iinclude  -I/home/demetres/Desktop/ks/arch/arm/include -include include/linux/autoconf.h -D__KERNEL__ -mlittle-endian -Iarch/arm/mach-versatile/include -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Os -marm -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mapcs -mno-sched-prolog -mabi=apcs-gnu -mno-thumb-interwork -D__LINUX_ARM_ARCH__=5 -march=armv5te -mtune=arm9tdmi -msoft-float -Uarm -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fno-stack-protector -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-dwarf2-cfi-asm -fconserve-stack -O1 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused -Wno-uninitialized -I/home/demetres/Desktop/rtl/include -DCONFIG_POWER_SAVING -DCONFIG_LITTLE_ENDIAN  -DMODULE -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(rtw_cmd)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(8192cu)"  -c -o /home/demetres/Desktop/rtl/core/rtw_cmd.o /home/demetres/Desktop/rtl/core/rtw_cmd.c
/bin/sh: scripts/basic/fixdep: cannot execute binary file
make[2]: *** [/home/demetres/Desktop/rtl/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 126
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/demetres/Desktop/rtl] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/demetres/Desktop/ks'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: try `V=1` option in command and paste the result

Comment: Question has been edited with the result of `make V=1`. I checked about missing files but there are exactly where they should be: `include/linux/autoconfig.h` and `include/config/auto.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

fixdep is an ARM binary and you are trying to run it on x86 machine(intel). You probably have to recompile kernel resources (just make them) and try cross compiling again.

Comment: In this case, can kernel sources be compiled on a x86 machine, or it is mandatory to have been compiled under ARM architecture?

Comment: Yes. You can compile on x86 machine for ARM. Isn't that's what you wanted. It's just that when you compile fixdep, make sure the elf built is for x86 and not arm.